# C++ destructor memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, destructor, delete-operator

Relatively simple question about handling destructors properly...

First I've got a class that's something like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    ReleaseObjects() {
        for (std::map<size_t, Object*>::iterator iter = objects.begin(); iter != objects.end(); iter++) {
            delete (*iter).second;
        }
        objects.clear();
    }

private:
    std::map<size_t,Object*> objects;
}
```

So the function simply deletes the objects, which were created using 'new'. Problem is an Object class:

```
class Bar : public Object {
public:
    Bar() {
        baz = new Baz();
    }

    ~Bar() { delete baz; }
private:
    Baz* baz;
}
```

If I add a type Baz object to Foo, and then try to ReleaseObjects(), I get a memory leak (valgrind). The issue points to baz being leaked, and I guess that means the destructor in bar is never called? So what I'd like to know is how to call the Bar destructor when trying to destroy that object (I can't alter the Bar class, but I can alter Foo).

Edit:
Oops, sorry for the syntax errors. Anyways, thanks for all the replies, silly me forgot to implement a proper destructor in my Baz class! Oh, and Baz is actually a template class, but I figured Baz was sort of irrelevant to my question, and that the problem was the destructor in Bar not being called... well, I was wrong, problem is in Baz after all. But thanks again, I think I got it figured out from here!

Comment: Is the destructor in Object virtual ? Post the Object class as well

Comment: This code did not leak.  This code did not even compile.  Please post actual code.

Comment: Can you post the class (or whatever it is) for Baz?

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete program that demonstrates the error. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: What specific error do you get?  And are you adding Baz to Foo, or Bar to Foo's map?  The "delete (*iter).second should be triggering Bar's destructor correctly.

Comment: Also, post something error free.  skimming through it, I see a few errors, a missing semi-colon after delete baz for example.

Comment: Calling delete on the Bar object in Foo calls the the Bar destructor. Also, is the Baz destructor defined? It could be that Baz is not properly cleaning itself up.

Comment: [Use RAII!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796/memory-management-in-c/77893#77893)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got to make sure that your destructor is virtual so that the proper derived destructor is called.

```
class Object {
 . . .
 virtual ~Object()
 . . .
};
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I forgot to implement! And I thought my problem was something else entirely... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your scenario, but [since you've got public inheritance, you probably want virtual destructors](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7). In particular, the base class (Object) needs a virtual destructor.

Note that your given code cannot compile. The new operator returns a pointer, so `baz` must be a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You should always always use smart pointers. These types behave like pointers but release memory automatically, and void the need for any such functions. They avoid all sorts of nasty bugs- potentially including this one, if you used a `shared_ptr<Bar>` and casted it down.

If you want to write non-trivial software in C++, you *must* know and understand smart pointers.

Comment: If the problem is a non-virtual destructor, I don't think a shared_ptr will work. (Not 100% sure though)

Comment: @MooingDuck: It uses type erasure for the destructor, and therefore *will* avoid this problem if you started at `Bar`.