# How to interpret this statement "A pointer in a function should not represent ownership"

Tags: c++, c++11

Based on [this](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative12/GN12Cpp11Style.pdf)

Stroustrup suggests that "A pointer in a function should not represent ownership"

**Question**> Can someone give me a little detail explanation? Best if an example is illustrated.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pointer is "owned" by some code if that code is responsible for deleting it, or for transferring ownership to someone else. Various smart pointers implement explicit ownership models. `shared_ptr` represents multiple pieces of code owning a pointer. `unique_ptr` represents only one piece of code that owns the pointer.

What he's saying is that if a function has a naked pointer (a pointer not in a smart pointer), it should *not* be considered to own it. If it is to claim some ownership of this pointer, it should either have been given a smart pointer as a parameter, or it should have stored the pointer it created with `new` in a smart pointer.

He's saying that only smart pointers own pointers. If a function takes a naked pointer as a parameter, it does not claim ownership of that pointer. If a function returns a naked pointer, *you* cannot claim ownership of that pointer.

Answer (score 5):

```
std::unique_ptr<int> pOwner(new int(5)); // this is the owner
int* pAccess = pOwner.get(); // this is a weak accessor, it does not own anything
```

He's talking about the role of raw pointers in a C++11 world. Owning pointers are meant to be `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` (they are the owners because they are responsible for deleting the object). Raw pointers should be used to access objects which are owned by a smart pointer. In C++11 you should basically never have a reason to explicitly call `delete` on a raw pointer anymore.

Comment: I would rather say there is no indication of ownership built into the semantics of RAW pointers thus it is unclear weather ownership is being transferred or shared. The reason I would rather use this as there exists real code with pointers were ownership is really being transfred: e.g. strdup() it is just that ownership is only explicitly expressed in the documentation and thus can not be verified/validated by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a dynamic object using `new`, some other object will be responsible for deleting it once it is no longer needed; that object is the dynamic object's "owner".

If you were to always refer to the object using plain pointers, then it's difficult to tell (without documentation) which of those pointers pointers represents ownership. If you pass a pointer to a function, then does the function take ownership? Or is the caller still responsible for deleting it? If you get that wrong, then you'll either not delete it (causing a resource leak, which might degrade your program's performance and eventually stop it from working), or you might delete it too soon (which can cause all manner of bugs, often very hard to track down).

A widely-used solution for this is to have a policy of always using smart pointers (objects that look like pointers, but contain logic to manage their target's lifetime) to denote ownership, and to never delete anything to which you just have a plain pointer. Then there is never any confusion about whether or not to delete something. The standard library provides smart pointers (`unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`) that give the common semantics of ownership by a single object, and ownership shared between multiple objects.

This is one aspect of the wider topic of resource management via [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796), which is extremely important in C++. As well as providing a clear ownership model, it is also the only sensible way to reliably prevent memory leaks when exceptions are thrown.