# When to use "delete"?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I want to store 10 `Obj` object in `objList`, but i don't know when is appropriate use `delete` in this case. If i use `delete Obj;` in the line where i note in below code, will the `Obj` still be stored in `objList`?

```
struct Obj {
    int u;
    int v;
};

vector<Obj> objList;

int main() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Obj *obj = new Obj();
        obj->u = i;
        obj->v = i + 1;
        objList.push_back(*obj);
        // Should i use "delete Obj;" here? 
    }
}
```

Comment: `new` is not required at all here..create the object on stack using `Obj obj;`.

Comment: And even if you did need `new`, then a simple `delete` wouldn't be sufficient - if `push_back` throws, then you've got a leak. You should always use [smart pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508) or other [RAII](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796) objects to manage dynamic resources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any object you create on the heap with `new` needs to be cleared up by `delete`. In your code, you are actually storing a copy in your collection.

```
objList.push_back(*Obj);
```

What this line is doing step by step is:

1. Indirecting a pointer to the underlying heap memory Obj occupies (returning the object `Obj`)
2. Calling the copy constructor to create a temporary copy
3. Storing the temporary copy in the collection

You do not need to create this initial Obj on the heap, a stack allocated local will suffice as @Luchian Grigore has pointed out.

```
Obj obj;
objList.push_back(obj);
```

You do not need to call delete on the copy in the collection, the STL collection will handle this memory itself when you remove the element, but you still will need to delete the original heap allocated object.

It would be better if you stored your objects by `std::shared_ptr`. That way delete would be called when all references to the Obj were removed.

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr< Obj > > vec;
vec.push_back( std::make_shared( new Obj() ) );
```

Comment: I was trying to point out the lifetime of the object in the heap space allocated by the collection doesn't have to be managed by the OP. :-)

Comment: Also, it's not stack and heap, but automatic and dynamic storage.

Comment: @Konrad, you mean when i use `objList.push_back(*obj);`, we store a "copy" of `*obj` in objList. So we don't have to worry about deleting obj. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @Mr.mr.: your understanding is wrong: in your code, you "newed" an Obj pointed to by obj, so you must delete it.  you don't have to worry about the copy of that Obj object.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you should.

There should be a corresponding `delete` for every `new` in your program.

**But** your program doesn't need dynamic allocation:

```
Obj obj;
obj.u = i;
obj.v = i + 1;
objList.push_back(obj);
```

Also, your syntax was wrong - `objList.push_back(*Obj); // should be *obj, not *Obj`

Answer (score 3):

Think about what happens:

In your loop you create a new instance of Obj and assign some values to it. This instance is created on your heap - thus you have to free it afterwards. When you add the instance to the vector you implicitely create a copy of it - because you have a vector of objects, not of pointers. Thus the vector keeps its own copy of Obj. You are safe to delete your Obj instance.

BTW:

- you could even reuse the object instance and create and free it outside of your loop
- it's not necessary to allocate the Obj instance on the heap

Obj x; x.u =i; x.v = i+1; objList.push_back(x);

would also do

You should read some articles about smart pointers and smart pointer containers. Eg. boost::scoped_ptr, boost::shared_ptr, std::auto_ptr. Using these paradigms there's usually no need to call delete by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You wanna use the heap, so I suggest changing your vector declaration to vector of pointers, something like this.

```
vector<Obj *>objList;
```

Why? Because if it is a vector of Obj's, then the things you're storing are actually copies of the value Obj of the pointers you created. objList's items and the obj pointers you create are totally separated and unrelated!
So when you,

```
delete obj
```

The things on objList are totally completely **unaffected** in any ways.
Moreover, `vector<Obj>` (no asterisk), stores its item as Obj and they are on the **stack**, they will disappear when your program goes out of scope!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simple rule is that each variable constructed by `new` should be clean up by `delete`.

However depending on your goal, you may not need write the `delete` yourself.

At home, when learning the gory details of memory management, you will probably write as many `delete` as you write `new`.

Professionals, however, never use `delete` in applicative code (*). `delete` is a code smell. It's the shortest way to memory leaks in the presence of exceptions. Professionals use RAII to deal with exceptions safely, and namely: smart pointers/smart containers.

(*) as opposed to library code, ie someone wrote that `shared_ptr` class one day.