# Array of pointers to diffrent-class objects that inherit from 1 base class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

So we say there is a base class A, and there are class B and class C that are inheritance of class A.

Now I want to create an array of pointers points to either B object or C object.

How can I do this?

Comment: Start by writing code?

Answer (score 3):

Pointers to a public base can point to objects derived of that base. Therefore you can do what you want like this:

```
A* arr[N];
```

Comment: but think about this, if B has a member called num, then when I tried to do this:arr[0].num, it tells me that num is not a member of A. ?

Comment: @andyz correct. If you want to access the members of `B`, then you can convert the pointer to `B*`.

Comment: ok. 1 more question. If I want to delete what arr[0] points to , should I do : delete arr[0]; arr[0]=NULL; or something else?

Comment: @andyz Does assigning a raw pointer to null delete the pointed object? The answer is no. For more info, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9888542/2079303