# How to clear the dynamically allocated memory, which is in Heap?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, destructor

Please have a look at the following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Memory
{
private:
    int *memory;

public:
    Memory()
    {
        memory = new int[3];

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            memory[i] = i;
            cout << memory[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    ~Memory()
    {
        delete[] memory;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Running" << endl;

    Memory m;
    // do I have to invoke ~Memory() ?

    int *secondMemory = new int[5];
    //How to clear the memory of 'secondMemory' ?

    system("pause");
    return 0;


}
```

In here, I have cleared the memory of the dynamically allocated `memory` array in the class's destructor. But my questions are

1. do I have to invoke ~Memory() ?
2. How to clear the memory of 'secondMemory' ?

These questions are asked as comments in the appropriate places of the code. Please help!

**Edit**

The problem here is, if I delete the memory of 'secondMemory' in main(), then the memory is gone as soon as it is allocated!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No, my cat ate it. Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/106508/560648 http://stackoverflow.com/q/8706192/560648 http://stackoverflow.com/q/76796/560648 **http://stackoverflow.com/q/6403055/560648**

Comment: Why are you worried about `secondMemory` being "gone as soon as it is allocated"? You are not using it anyway... If you were to do something with it, then obviously you would need to perform the release *after* using it.

Comment: @LucTouraille: Thanks for the reply. My mock paper has asked a question in this way. "What happens to the memory if we delete it?" is the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> do I have to invoke ~Memory() ?

No, objects with *automatic storage duration* (like `m`) get destroyed when they go out of scope. In other words, the destructor is automatically called by the system. In this case, `m` gets destroyed upon returning from the `main()` function.

> How to clear the memory of 'secondMemory' ?

Every object allocated with `new` must be destroyed through a corresponding call to `delete`, and every array allocated with `new[]` must be destroyed with a corresponding call to `delete[]`:

```
delete[] secondMemory;
```

Failing to do so results in *memory leaks*.

However, keep in mind that using raw pointers to perform manual memory management is regarded as a **bad programming practice** in Modern C++. Rather use standard containers, like `std::vector<>`, whenever you can.

Comment: ok, but you mean I have to call it just after the memory allocation? I mean, just down the  int *secondMemory = new int[5]; ? Then, the memory is allocated, and it is gone within mili seconds!

Comment: @Yohan: You have to deallocate the memory before you lose the last reference to it. In this case, you have to `delete[]` it before you return from `main()` (but you can do it *any time* before returning from `main()`).

Comment: Btw, this "Modern C++" style thing consists of using RAII, which is a feature that was already in the language in the 1990s. Yes, it's *that* modern.

Comment: @Andy I've been seeing a lot of claims that this is a bad practice lately. Do you have a definitive source for that? While I agree that it is overused and most cases could be replaced by a standard container, it is still a fundamental part of C++ memory management in general. I feel, especially for someone just learning the language, they should have a clear understanding of how this works before moving on to containers and other advanced concepts like RAII.

Comment: @DaveRager: I understand what you mean, but I actually see things the other way round. Learners should first get familiar with the higher-level abstractions and concepts that the language and its standard library offer, and only after delve into the low-level details of how those things are implemented, and how to obtain maximum control over memory allocation.

Comment: @Yohan Why do you think you have to deallocate the memory right after you've allocated it? What would be the purpose in that?

Comment: @JBentley: Thanks for the reply. It is a very good point. hmm... Yes, I have understood it incorrectly..

Comment: @everyone: Basically, I am a Java programmer. OK, C++ programmer too, but not 'old' as Java. This question has been asked in my degree mock paper. I am practicing the questions and answers, before I face to the real exam :)

Comment: @Yohan: OK, good luck with your exam :)

Comment: @AndyProwl: Anyway, after the delete[] I have to do 'memory=0' and 'secondMemory=0' right? To prevent it from re-allocating?

Comment: @Yohan: No, you don't have to. And in any case that wouldn't help preventing reallocation. that would just help figuring out that deallocation has been done (by checking `if (secondMemory == 0)` before possibly dereferencing `secondMemory`). In the case of `memory`, that's not even legal, because `memory` is an object of type `Memory`, not a pointer, so you can't assign zero to it (unless you have an overloaded `operator =`, but that would be non-sense in this case).

Answer (score 4):

> do I have to invoke ~Memory()

No, destructors are invoked automatically when the object falls out of scope.

> How to clear the memory of 'secondMemory'?

Use `delete[] secondMemory;`

Comment: -1 for unsafe `delete[]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Memory m;
// do I have to invoke ~Memory() ?
```

No this is not dynamically allocated so the compiler calls the destructor for you when `m` goes out of scope. In this case when `main` returns.

```
int *secondMemory = new int[5];
//How to clear the memory of 'secondMemory' ?
```

This is allocated dynamically so you have to deallocate it.

```
delete [] secondMemory;
```

Comment: -1 for unsafe `delete[]`.

Comment: @DeadMG How please explain.

Comment: No protection from exceptions, from multiple return paths, from double deletes, from accessing after freeing, etc?

Comment: @DeadMG none of those apply in the example code given. I believe your downvotes are unfair and stating that it is unsafe is misleading.

Comment: @DeadMG Those points are beyond the scope of this question - it's a shame you downvoted all the answers on that basis.

Comment: @DeadMG drawing your sword on a fly here :)

Answer (score 2):

> do I have to invoke ~Memory() ?

When the object goes out of scope, `~Memory()` will automatically be invoked.  So no, you don't have to do anything to invoke it manually.

> How to clear the memory of 'secondMemory' ?

Just use

```
delete [] secondMemory
```

since you initialized `int* secondMemory` using new and [].

Comment: -1 for unsafe `delete[]`.