# How do smart pointers know when to free the resources on program crash?

Tags: c++

How does a c++ project using smart pointers like unique_ptr's know to free the resources when the program crashes?

Comment: You want to lookup stack unwinding. And also define _crash_ more exactly. If the program aborts all memory will be to the OS anyways.

Comment: It depends on the "crash" - terminate will not unwind the stack, so destructors won't get called. There are some genral musing (about RAII) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796/general-guidelines-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-c/77893#77893

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the program crashes "gracefully" due to a handled exception, the stack unwinding will call the destructors on any smart pointers and free the memory.

For complete crashes (e.g. segmentation fault, call to `std::terminate()`), it is the operating system that will free any memory and resources held by the program.

Answer (score 1):

When a C++ program crashes, it exits. The operating system cleans up any OS resources it may have asked for, which includes memory, but also other resources (file handles for example).

Thus, C++ does not clean up - the operating system does. What once was the C++ heap is returned to the operating system as free memory.